# How to make draggable element invisible while it reverting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have dragable element in my html. and jQuery is like this

```
$( ".block-33a" ).sortable({
      revert: true
});

$( ".hidden_drag" ).draggable({
    revert: true,
    stop: function(event,ui){
    //some code
    }
});
```

by using this u can able to get my element back to the default place but it should be invincible while it is reverting. how do i do it?

**UPDATE**

this is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Q2h2w/46/

and it will say my requirement too

Comment: have you created any fiddle for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the fiddle. Please have a look at it.
I have added the `mouseup` event to detect mouse release. Hope that will solve your purpose:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q2h2w/56/

```
var count=0;
$('.button_area').draggable({
        revert: true,
        drag: function(){
            count++;
        },
        stop: function(event,ui){
                $('.button_area').off("mouseup");
                $(this).show();
        },
        start: function( event, ui ) {
            $('.button_area').on("mouseup",function(){
                $(this).hide();
            });
        }
});
```